# How to constantly trigger an event when hovered over that element?

Tags: javascript

So, I have a button and I want to constantly have an event triggering when the button is hovered. If I use `mouseover`, then this event triggers only once when the cursor comes on it from somewhere outside.

```
btn.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    console.log("Hello");
});
```

For instance, I want this console log to happen constantly while the cursor is over the button.

Comment: You're always listening for the event. It's only triggered when the mouse moves into the button.

Comment: @Barmar Updated my question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this by using `mouseover` and `mouseout` (and a `setInterval`).  Basically, start an interval when the mouse enters, and clear it when it exits.

```
let interval;

btn.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        console.log("Hello");
    }, 100);
});

btn.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
    clearInterval(interval);
});
```

Comment: @Barmar There's `mouseover` vs `mouseenter` and there's `mouseout` vs `mouseleave`.  I forget the differences, but I think it's something with bubbling to parent elements.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, sorry, `mouseexit` was a typo :-P

Comment: Is this the only way of doing this?

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee I don't think this is the only way, but it's how I might solve this problem.  `setInterval` is usually what you want when you want to run something over and over again (and be able to kill it).  Are there concerns with this solution?

Answer (score 3):

Please check if `mousemove` event works for you.

```js
let interval = null;
btn.addEventListener("mousemove", function(){
    console.log("Hello");
});

btn.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
  interval= setInterval(()=>console.log('Hello'), 100)
})

btn.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
 clearInterval(interval)
})
```

```css
#btn{
    width: 300px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
    <button  id="btn">
    hover me
    </button>
```

Comment: `mousemove` is definitely better than `mouseover` but if the cursor stays still inside the button the event doesn't trigger.

Comment: Definitely @SomShekharMukherjee. This solution might not work for still cursor. I believe a combination of setInterval with mouseover, mouseout with this approach gives better event system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of

- flags, either on the elements themselves as here, or as separate variable(s)
- a setInterval function

to figure out which elements are being hovered at any given time. (This is obviously a slightly silly example since you can't very well mouse-over multiple elements that sit next to each other at a time.)

```js
function addEventListeners(button) {
  button.addEventListener("mouseover", () => button.dataset.hovered = "1");
  button.addEventListener("mouseout", () => button.dataset.hovered = "0");
}

function reportHovers(elements) {
  const hoveredIds = elements.filter(el => el.dataset.hovered === "1").map(el => el.id);
  document.getElementById("out").value = `${Math.floor(new Date() / 1000)}\n${JSON.stringify(hoveredIds)}`;
}


var buttons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("button"));
buttons.forEach(button => addEventListeners(button));
setInterval(() => reportHovers(buttons), 100);
```

```html
<button id="b1">Button 1</button>
<button id="b2">Button 2</button>
<button id="b3">Button 3</button>

<textarea id="out"></textarea>
```